# How to vertically justify R Shiny radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

Any guidance please on how to arrange the buttons in the app below into a neat straight line while still inheriting the ‘center’ alignment from the column? I am looking to keep the column’s ‘centre’ alignment so that the buttons line up under the “Center Aligned Title”, however this then lines up each choice in an erratic manner, dependent on the length of the choice.

```
library(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    column(4),
    column(4,
           fluidRow(
             column(12,
                    align = 'center',
                    h6('Center Aligned Title')
                    )
           ),
           fluidRow(
             column(12,
                    align = 'center',
                    # align = 'left', # This justifies/arranges the buttons neatly
                    # but not underneath "Center Aligned Title"
                    radioButtons(
                      inputId = 'my_btns',
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c('abc','defg','hijllm','no'),
                      selected = character(0),
                      inline = F
                    )
                    )
           )
           ),
    column(4)
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)

runApp(app)
```

Comment: Umm...why not use `inline = TRUE` in `radioButtons` ?

Comment: Hi. Because that just puts them in 1 horizontal line. I am looking to keep them stacked (with a better justification/alignment)

Comment: Where exactly do you want the header and radio buttons to appear? Have you tried removing `align='center'` from both?

Comment: If I remove `align='center'` then it defaults to the left of the column, which means that it won’t end up in the center of the page, but rather slightly off center. I thought that there would maybe be a bit of css that would align the radiobutton choices to the top choice, but still pretty much in the center of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could drop `align = 'center'` in the second `column()` and use CSS to align the radio buttons in a flexbox like this:

```r
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      #my_btns, #my_div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      }"
      ))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
        align = 'center',
        h6('Center Aligned Title')
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
        div(
          radioButtons(
            inputId = 'my_btns',
            label = NULL,
            choices = c('abc','defg','hijllm','no'),
            selected = character(0),
            inline = F
          ), id = "my_div")
        )  
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Martin C. Arnold, that is exactly what I was hoping for.